# Invalid BLOB ID in Firebird 2.5

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I get invalid blob id when accessing field with type "BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80".
I use latest firebird 2.5. I dont set any "character set".

What cause this problem? Is it because i dont set "character set"?

Comment: Do you only get it with this blob type, or also with others? Please show some code in context. Most likely you closed the (statement) cursor or the statement itself, or committed the transaction before you accessed the blob.

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. The field type was varchar(30). After i change it to blob, i get this problem. But when i create field2 and copy the value, then change the field type and copy back the value to field1, i dont get this error. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Did you alter the type of column from `VARCHAR(30)` to `BLOB`? I would have thought that wouldn't be allowed. If so, it might be a bug.

Comment: I altered it. I thought it wouldnt be posible too.

Comment: What is a character set of your database?

Comment: none. I dont set any character set